# How to get name of recently installed app?

Tags: android

My code gets a list of all recently installed apps, but the problem is, I only want the most recent package name (only one). How do I modify my code to do that?

```
public void RootInstallAPK1(View view) {
    final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm
            .getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

    for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
        String packageName = packageInfo.packageName;
        String appFile = packageInfo.sourceDir;
        long lastModified = new File(appFile).lastModified();
        // Use this to get first time install time
        // long installed =
        // context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(packageName,
        // 0).firstInstallTime;
        Log.d(TAG, "Installed package :" + packageName);
        Log.d(TAG, "Source dir : " + appFile);
        Log.d(TAG, "Last Modified Time :" + lastModified);

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, packageName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already looping all installed, and getting the last modified date, this is pretty simple from here.

```
long newestInstall = 0;
ApplicationInfo newestApp;

for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {

    String appFile = packageInfo.sourceDir;
    long lastModified = new File(appFile).lastModified();

    // check if this is newer then what we already have
    if ( lastModified > newestInstall ) {

        newestInstall = lastModified;
        newestApp = packageInfo;
    }
}

// print the newest app to the log
Log.d(TAG, "Newest App :" + newestApp.packageName);
```

This will loop through all installed packages, and continue to update *newestTime* and *newestApp*, for each app that is newer then the last.

Once the loop has finished, you will be left with the most recently installed app.

Comment: It is somewhat pseudo code that you should be able to figure out. I am showing / explaining the process that you should use.

Comment: All i did was reuse your code... You have `packages` already defined, why did you delete it.